# What does this size mean in css {font: 14px/24px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif}

Tags: css, font-size

What is 14px/24px here? Which is the real font size?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It's the shorthand for the different font related properties. It means:

```
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 24px;

font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
```

See: http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-font-shorthand-property-cheat-sheet/

[image]

Comment: if it is the case then, 
font: normal normal normal 80px/1 "austera-font";
or
font-size: 80px;
line-height:1;
should work same, right? but its not the case in my project!!

Comment: @SohilShah: I can't see the problem from that demo. There is probably something else affecting it in your project. Most of those properties are being set in `icons.css` line 28 already.

Answer (score 6):

First is `font-size` the second is `line-height`

Quote from the [specification for font shorthand](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-shorthand)

> '**font**'
>       Value:    [ [ <'font-style'> || <'font-variant'> || <'font-weight'> ]?
>   **<'font-size'> [ / <'line-height'> ]?**
>   <'font-family'> ] | caption | icon |
>   menu | message-box | small-caption |
>   status-bar | inherit

Answer (score 3):

This is equivalent to

```
#html{
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:24px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```