# explanation for font: bold 12px/25px "Arial";

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does this size mean in css {font: 14px/24px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083192/what-does-this-size-mean-in-css-font-14px-24px-arial-helvetica-sans-serif)

i see around the website there is CSS like this

```
 .selector {font: bold 12px/25px "Arial";}
```

i understand bold mean font-weight and "Arial" is Font-family.
but what about **12px/25px** ?

can someone please explain what is that mean?

thank you in advance,
GusDe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two figures in `12px/25px` represent `font-size` and `line-height`.

This is the standard short-hand notation for the `font` style. See here for a breakdown of all possible options: http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-font-shorthand-property-cheat-sheet/

Answer (score 1):

The part before the slash is the fontsize and the part after it the line height.

See the docs here:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-shorthand